uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
Recently when i was coding, i suddenly got an error for no reason. After looking for ways of solving it i put in some code and now, i got a whole new one. The front end works on vite and is writtten on javascript.
The first error
The second error
import { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import { response } from 'express'

function App() {
  const [Password, SetPassword] = useState('')
  const [Username, SetUsername] = useState('')

  const onSubmit = () => {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      Username: Username, // No need to wrap Username in an object
      Password: Password
    })
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status == 200){
      alert('Matched!')
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(response)
    })
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div class='mainDiv  --centered'>

      <input class='UsernameBox --verticallycentered' placeholder='Username/Email/Phone' value={Username} onChange={(e) => SetUsername(e.target.value)}></input>
      

      <input class='PasswordBox --verticallycentered' placeholder='Password' value={Password} onChange={(e) => SetPassword(e.target.value)}></input>
      <h4 className='ErrorThingy'>Passwords can only contain Letters, numbers and symbols</h4>
      <button onClick={onSubmit} className='LoginBtn --centered'> Log in</button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App



This part in the front end is problematic: import { response } from 'express'.
I guess it was automatically added by an editor because you tried console.error(response), where response was not in the scope. I think it should be console.error(error) instead.

As the other people said, the response from express is not needed, import useState correctly from react too it should be import React, { useState } from 'react'; also use className instead of class and use === for strict equality

Its because you are importing express into a client side app.

The code was working perfectly fine when I just imported it. And I tried commenting it. It didn’t solve the problem.
